# Is it possible to find RBIs of multiple exchanges based on one criterion?

Tags: r, pine-script, exchange-server, tradingview-api

Here is an example of that MA cross code.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="MA Cross", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

shortlen = input.int(9, "Short MA Length", minval=1)
longlen = input.int(21, "Long MA Length", minval=1)
short = ta.sma(close, shortlen)
long = ta.sma(close, longlen)

plot(short, color = #FF6D00)
plot(long, color = #43A047)

plot(ta.cross(short, long) ? short : na, color=#2962FF, style = plot.style_cross, linewidth = 4)
```

There is a slight difference when comparing binance and coinbase to their code.

(because the volume and price are slightly different)

Can I get a RBI on Coinbase based on a cross ma confirmed on Binance?

Answer (score 0):

You can request data from different exchanges by using the `request.security()` function.

Below example requests the `volume` information from Binance and Coinbase. The ticker is the same `BTCUSDT`, only difference is the exchange.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", format=format.volume)

vol_binance = request.security("BINANCE:BTCUSDT", timeframe.period, volume)
vol_coinbase = request.security("COINBASE:BTCUSDT", timeframe.period, volume)

plot(vol_binance, color=color.green)
plot(vol_coinbase, color=color.red)
```

[image]